# Why can't Firefox cope with a memory limit set by ulimit?

Tags: firefox, memory, ulimit

When I set a memory limit for firefox using:

```
$ ulimit -Sv 512000
$ ulimit -v
512000
$ firefox %u
```

I get the following error:

```
[4881] ###!!! ABORT: PR_CreateThread failed!: file /builddir/build/BUILD/firefox-49.0/firefox-49.0/js/xpconnect/src/XPCJSRuntime.cpp, line 1045
[4881] ###!!! ABORT: PR_CreateThread failed!: file /builddir/build/BUILD/firefox-49.0/firefox-49.0/js/xpconnect/src/XPCJSRuntime.cpp, line 1045
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

However, if Firefox is already running, it opens a new window without any errors.

What is the issue with setting a ulimit for Firefox?

The OS is Fedora 24: `4.7.5-200.fc24.x86_64`

Comment: It's a major bug in Firefox that is now 14 years old. Firefox CRASHES, sometimes freezing the ENTIRE OPERATIONG SYSTEM, when it runs out of memory. It's one reason you should never use Firefox, and they shouldn't even be in the software business. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=336807

Answer (score 1):

Firefox is just a memory hog; 512M of virtual address space isn't enough to run it. In my experiments, I couldn't get a busy session started without `ulimit -v` set to at least 1.5G.

It works for you when firefox is already running because in that case you don't start a new firefox process (which would inherit the ulimit) but just tell the already running one to open a new window.